# AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics: Argument list too long

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-redux, parameter-passing

When I do **react-native link**, it will install **AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics** and **AppCenterReactNativeCrashes**. After doing link, when I try to run the project it will give me following errors:

```
Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at /Users/PROJ_PATH/PROJ_NAME/node_modules/appcenter-analytics/ios/../../../ios/Pods/React/node_modules/merge-stream.
```

And

```
Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at /Users//PROJ_PATH/PROJ_NAME//node_modules/appcenter-crashes/ios/../../../ios/Pods/React/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist/test
```

I check **headerSearchPath** and its seems ok. Can anyone tell me what is the issue which I do?

Comment: Have you opened your project from .xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj?

Comment: Yeah, I opened workspace.

Comment: If any solution then please let me know. I am facing same issue.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?